# CSWP Blog profile picture

Tags: search, search-results, item-styles, cswp

I would like to create a Content Search Web Part that displays the user profile picture of each blog entry/creator next to the blog title from a Team Blog site (and roll that up to display the latest 3 blog entries on the teams homepage). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to created custom display template according to your requirement and use that display template in you CSWP.

Comment: Can I not use a default picture one and point the picture url to the profile?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of reference material that shows how to do that?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1.aspx may be this will help you to start with display templates.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the Author information to look up the user profile and then return the User Profile Photo. You can do this with the JavaScript client side object model or with REST. Either way it is not trivial but can be done.